Club similar events into a single row based on dates
Problem: Need help to club events running on same weeks into a single row.
Data input is at Event-Start Date (Sunday) - End Date (Saturday).
For events having same start date and overlapping period, need to club into a single row
Please see input in the screenshot -

E1, E2, E3 all starts at same date but end dates are not exactly same. E3 is running for an additional week. Therefore, Clubbed E1, E2, E3 into same event for the overlapping period. For the additional period E3 was running, a separate row is created for that particular week.

E4 is also overlapping for week falling in mid, this need not be clubbed since its start date is different.

Criteria to club events in a same row is events having same start dates

Start dates are always Sundays, End dates are always Saturdays

SQL Server or Spark SQL solution would work


Please help. I have tried using windows functions
Input -



Event
Start Date (Sunday)
End Date (Saturday)




E1
5/5/2024
5/25/2024


E2
5/5/2024
5/25/2024


E3
5/5/2024
6/1/2024


E4
5/12/2024
5/18/2024



Output -



Event
Start Date (Sunday)
End Date (Saturday)




E1,E2,E3
5/5/2024
5/25/2024


E3
5/26/2024
6/1/2024


E4
5/12/2024
5/18/2024



Code:
select Start_Date, coalesce(CONCAT_WS(',', COLLECT_SET(DISTINCT Event)), 'NA') 
from Input
group by Start_Date

Please help figure out how can events be split basis overlap

(1) Please do not post data as an image. Post as text or a markdown table that we can cut & paste to test out potential solutions. (2) Show us what you have tried, so that we can modify and build on your attempt instead of making us start from scratch. I've recently done something similar with the date-range logic in this answer, but that solution requires significant changes for your case. I and others are willing to help, but you need to give us more to work with.

Let's say two further events E5 and E6 exist. E5 started 5/7/24 and ended 5/25/24. E6 started 5/10/24 and ended 6/1/24. What result would then be correct? Your question is very vague and misses to explain all possible cases.

@JonasMetzler - My interpretation is that rule 2 would place the new events on separate result rows, like E4. (bSXR4um6)

Thanks for guiding me through the guidelines and best practices. @TN - Will update the problem statement.

@JonasMetzler - Start dates will be all Sundays and end dates will be all Saturdays. Criteria to club events is same start date. In that case, E5 and E6 will be separate row

@TN I added the tables as markdown and its showing correctly in preview, but not showing correctly after question is posted. I have updated the problem statement, please help open query and please let me know if I should incorporate any other feedback

Side question: What is meant by the term "club"? I am unfamiliar with this usage of that word in this context.

By "club", I meant bring together in a same record

Steps:

Define groups with same StartDate thru dense_rank()by StartDate.
Define rows in this groups with different EndDate - also dense_rank() - grn2.
Add previous rows with grn2>1 to ranges with shift of StartDate
Group by grn,grn2
See example

with tr as(
select *
  ,dense_rank()over(order by startDate)grn
  ,dense_rank()over(partition by startDate order by EndDate)grn2
  ,min(endDate)over(partition by StartDate)grEnddate
from events
)
,allRanges as(
select event,startDate,grEndDate EndDate,grn,1 grn2 from tr
union all
select event,dateadd(d,1,grEndDate) StartDate,EndDate,grn,grn2 from tr
where grn2>1
)
-- select * from tr;
select grn,grn2,string_agg(event,',')events
  ,min(StartDate) StartDate
  ,min(enddate)EndDate
from allRanges
group by grn,grn2
order by grn,grn2

with test data (I will add several rows)



Event
StartDate
EndDate




E1
2024-05-05
2024-05-25


E2
2024-05-05
2024-05-25


E3
2024-05-05
2024-06-01


E3-2
2024-05-05
2024-06-01


E4
2024-05-12
2024-05-18


E4-2
2024-05-18
2024-05-25



output is



grn
grn2
events
StartDate
EndDate




1
1
E1,E2,E3,E3-2
2024-05-05
2024-05-25


1
2
E3,E3-2
2024-05-26
2024-06-01


2
2
E4
2024-05-12
2024-05-18


3
3
E4-2
2024-05-18
2024-05-25



Demo

The above may need tome tweaking. I added another event set, but got some unexpected results. fiddle.

Corrected:select event,startDate,grEndDate EndDate,grn,1 grn2 from tr in union. Output with your test data matches with your query. (https://dbfiddle.uk/DihsUe9e)

(updated and reposted) I would expect a "E8,E9" combo for the 2024-06-09 to 2024-06-15 range. This fiddle might be a fix.

Thank you. Yes, it seems more logical this way. I will update my answer.

One solution is to:

Partition the data into groups by start date (so that only events with the same start dates will be combined).
Gather, sort, and de-dup all start and end dates in each group.
Use those dates to construct non-overlapping date ranges.
Join those date ranges with the events for that group having overlapping date ranges. A standard test for overlapping ranges is start1 < end2 AND start2 < end1.
Group by date range and use the STRING_AGG() function to combine the matching event names.

When working with date or date/time ranges, it is often easier to work with half-open intervals, where the start date is inclusive, but the end-date is exclusive (00:00 of the day after the last included date). This way, the end date of one interval is precisely equal to the start date of the adjacent following interval. Calculations just work better this way without repeated +/- 1 adjustments. The end-date can be adjusted back for end-user presentation.
-- Partition by original event StartDate, then split/combine all overlaps
;WITH CTE_AdjustedEvents AS (
    SELECT
        Event,
        StartDate,
        DATEADD(day, 1, EndDate) AS EndDateExcl -- Adjust to excludive end-date
    FROM Events
),
CTE_Dates AS (
    SELECT StartDate AS GroupDate, StartDate AS Date FROM CTE_AdjustedEvents
    UNION -- implicitly DISTINCT
    SELECT StartDate AS GroupDate, EndDateExcl AS Date FROM CTE_AdjustedEvents
),
CTE_DateRanges AS (
    SELECT
        GroupDate,
        Date AS StartDate, 
        LEAD(Date) OVER(PARTITION BY GroupDate ORDER BY Date) AS EndDateExcl
    FROM CTE_Dates
)
SELECT
    DR.GroupDate,
    STRING_AGG(AE.Event, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY AE.Event) AS EventList,
    DR.StartDate,
    DATEADD(day, -1, DR.EndDateExcl) AS EndDate -- Adjust back to original inclusive end-date
FROM CTE_AdjustedEvents AE
JOIN CTE_DateRanges DR
    ON DR.GroupDate = AE.StartDate
    AND DR.StartDate < AE.EndDateExcl
    AND AE.StartDate < DR.EndDateExcl
GROUP BY DR.GroupDate, DR.StartDate, DR.EndDateExcl
ORDER BY DR.GroupDate, DR.StartDate

Results:



GroupDate
EventList
StartDate
EndDate




2024-05-05
E1,E2,E3
2024-05-05
2024-05-25


2024-05-05
E3
2024-05-26
2024-06-01


2024-05-12
E4
2024-05-12
2024-05-18



As an alternative, if you with to combine all events having overlapping date ranges, you can eliminate the initial partitioning by removing all references to GroupDate from the above code. With this logic, the E4 event would show up for a week in the middle of the E1, E2, E3 series.



EventList
StartDate
EndDate




E1,E2,E3
2024-05-05
2024-05-11


E1,E2,E3,E4
2024-05-12
2024-05-18


E1,E2,E3
2024-05-19
2024-05-25


E3
2024-05-26
2024-06-01



See this db<>fiddle for a demo.
You have tagged your question with both [sql-server] and [apache-spark-sql]. My answer is a pure SQL Server answer. I do not know Apache Spark, but you might need to replace the STRING_AGG() function with something like the CONCAT_WS(',', COLLECT_SET(...)) functions from your original post.
